# How to create extension to shared method

Tags: .net, vb.net

I like to create an extension method to Image.FromStream

```
Public Shared Function FromStream(ByVal stream As System.IO.Stream) As System.Drawing.Image
```

With possibility to cancel processing like

```
Public Shared Function FromStream(ByVal stream As System.IO.Stream, ByVal CloseTask As ManualResetEvent) As System.Drawing.Image
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can only add extension methods which appear to add *instance* methods to a type - you can't make it look like you've added new *shared* methods to a type.

Answer (score 1):

I have a somewhat dodgy way I do shared extensions.

I use the Extensions class to resolve the conflict in having the same signature for my functions

```
Module Main
    Public Class Extensions
        Public Class [Boolean]
            Public Shared Function TryParse(ByVal strValue As String, ByRef blnResult As Boolean) As Boolean
                If Not Object.Equals(strValue, Nothing) Then
                    If strValue = "Y" Then
                        blnResult = True
                        Return True
                    End If

                    If strValue = "N" Then
                        blnResult = False
                        Return True
                    End If
                End If

                Return Boolean.TryParse(strValue, blnResult)
            End Function
        End Class
    End Class

End Module
```